# Logit function and probability

Tags: statistics

I was reading a paper regarding using a logistic regression to predict an outcome of interest. In the paper the logit is given as

logit(p) = log[p/1-p] = b0 + b1*x1 + .... + bn*xn => Which is fine

but then p is given as

p = 1/exp[-(b0 + b1*x1 + .... bn*xn)]  => Which I don't understand.

It should be p = 1/(1 + exp[-(b0 + b1*x1 + .... + bn*xn)]), then the probability will be between 0 and 1, right?

Thank you for your time.

--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ell = \log \frac{p}{1-p}$ then $\ell = \log\left(-1 + \frac{1}{1-p}\right)$.  The advantage of this last way of writing it is that $p$ only appears once.  So just invert step-by-step:
$$
\begin{align}
e^\ell & = -1 + \frac{1}{1-p} \\
1 + e^\ell & = \frac{1}{1-p} \\
\frac{1}{1+e^\ell} & = 1-p \\
p & = 1 - \frac{1}{1+e^\ell} = \frac{(1+e^\ell) - 1}{1+e^\ell} = \frac{e^\ell}{1+e^\ell}
\end{align}
$$
Multiplying the numerator and denominator both by $e^{-\ell}$ yields:
$$
p = \frac{1}{e^{-\ell}+1}.
$$
Now put the appropriate expression in place of $\ell$.

So your answer is right and the one that was "given" is not.